# How can I review a smartphone sensors readings on a Dell gateway?

Tags: snappy, linux

I have got a [Dell edge gateway 5000](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/dell-edge-gateway-5000_User's%20Guide_en-us.pdf) with Linux Snappy 15.04 as OS.

I have installed the gateway access point and I can connect the gateway from my smartphone. Now, I need to read the smartphone sensors like accelerometer, touch screen co-ordinates, light, and so on.

The smartphone is an HTC M9 with Android 7.0.

Comment: Please add some link, doc about the gateway.

Comment: What smartphone do you have? You have to add this information in the question (Android, iOS, Windows phone, ...)

Comment: this is the user guide for the gateway 
http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/dell-edge-gateway-5000_User's%20Guide_en-us.pdf 

and I have updated my post

Comment: If you are not going to code it yourself, I believe that your best approach is to ask at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, not here, since you are asking us to provide a software application

Answer (score 2):

From sensors you can register a listener to sensor events [1] and on every value you send it to a ByteArrayWriter/Listener pair over socket connection [2].

Socket needs only WLAN from the gateway, the rest of it is java code [3].

Complete solution needs some coding effort with the building blocks I gave.

[1] https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777692/android-streaming-sensor-data-continuously

[3] http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-make-a-socket-connection-to-a-server.html